# Link to Organisation tab MS Teams

Tags: deep-linking, microsoft-teams

What I am trying to get is an URL that will take me directly to the **organisation tab of a specific user** in Microsoft Teams.

I know that for example https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=me@contoso.com will take me to a chat with me@contoso.com, however I would like the "organisation" tab, instead ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgHzA.png)).

I tried something like: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/organisation/0/0?users=me@contoso.com but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by an organization tab. Could you please elaborate more on what you are looking for? You can have an app(tab) pinned to a specific user.

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of the Organization tab in the post - hope it helps to clarify.

Comment: This is just a tab. There is no api that could get you this hierarchy. You would need to build this tab yourself.